# Can a function be increasing *at a point*?

Tags: functions, soft-question, definition

From what I understand we say that a function is increasing on an interval $I$ if
$$
x_1 < x_2 \quad\Rightarrow\quad f(x_1) < f(x_2).
$$
for all $x_1,x_2\in I$. I understand that some might call this *strictly increasing* and allow for equality when saying *increasing*.

We know that when a function is differentiable on the interval $I$, then **if** $f'(x) > 0$ on $I$ **then** $f$ is increasing on $I$. But here we have to be careful because if $f(x) = x^3$ then $f$ indeed is increasing on $\mathbb{R}$ even though $f'(0) = 0$. So we can't conclude that if $f$ is increasing, then $f'(x)$ must be positive on the interval.

Also, even though $f(x) = x^2$, then $f$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$ even though $f'(0) = 0$.

My question is

> Does it make sense to talk about a function being increasing at a point?

The only definition I can think of making is to say that $f$ is increasing at a point $a$ if $f'(a) > 0$. But the problems with saying this is that then the function given by $f(x) = x^3$ is not increasing at $0$ even thought it is increasing on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

I am aware ([from here](http://sites.msudenver.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/385/2017/05/IncrAtPt_New.pdf)) of the example with
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) + \frac{x}{2} & \text{if }x\neq 0 \\ 0 & \text{if } x = 0\end{cases}.
$$
This function is differentiable at $0$ with $f'(0) = \frac{1}{2} > 0$. For $x\neq 0$ we have $f'(x) = 2x\sin(1/x) - \cos(1/x) + 1/2$. And so for all $x_k = \frac{1}{2k\pi}$ we have $f'(\frac{1}{2k\pi}) = -\frac{1}{2} < 0$. That is, there is not interval around $0$ where $f$ is increasing. And so it shouldn't really make sense to say that $f$ is increasing at $0$.

One example I can think of where it maybe should make sense to take about a function being increasing at a point is when when we take the derivative of function $s(t)$ that gives the position of a particle. The derivative is then the velocity $v(t) = s'(t)$. And maybe this is just a language issue, but here it sounds reasonable saying that if $v(a)>0$ then the velocity is positive at time $t=a$ and so the *rate of change* is positive at $a$. This is almost saying that the position is increasing at that point.

Again, my question is just if it makes sense to talk about a function being increasing (or decreasing) *at a point*. If so, how is this defined?

Comment: I guess it makes sense to say around a point.

Comment: @AnilBaseski: Yes, I agree that it makes sense to say that a function is increasing around a point if by that we mean that there is some interval around the point where $f$ is increasing.

Comment: The derivative can be defined as the rate of change of f relative to a change of x. If we say that x is fixed then the definition is non-sense. I guess in the definition it is assumed that x is not fixed, which follows x is not a point.

Comment: First off be careful with your example $f(x)=x^3$. You are using the first derivative test to characterize the notion of increase at a critical point. That's not allowed. The derivative is just a tool to help investigate the nature of a function, it can't be used to define the notion of increasing. Considerthe function where $f(x) = x+1$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x) = 0$ when $x \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$. This is increasing and not differentiable.

Comment: @mtiano: But that is my question. In my question I note that it doesn't really make sense to say that a function is increasing at a point if the derivative at the point is positive. So my questions is: Can we make sense of it? Also, in your example I guess that the function isn't increasing? ($f(1) = 2 > f(\pi) = 0$)

Comment: Did you realize that your given piece wise function is indeed differentiable at x=0, but the derivative is not continuous at x=0?

Comment: @imranfat: Yes, I did notice that. I guess that is the point about not defining a function to be *increasing at a point when the derivative is positive*. The example shows that in this case there is not small interval around $0$ where the function is increasing (the derivative is not continuous).

Comment: Yep, that continuity of the derivative should not be taken lightly :)))

Comment: @imranfat: True. It is too often just assumed :)

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://clem.mscd.edu/~talmanl/PDFs/APCalculus/IncrAtPt_New.pdf).  I do not think there is any obvious way to define increasing at a point other than what you have already discussed in your question.

Comment: Doesn't the [PDF](http://sites.msudenver.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/385/2017/05/IncrAtPt_New.pdf) (Talman, On Functions “Increasing at a Point”) you linked to already suggest (p. 3, first paragraph) the definition that Did gave below? (And it also gives a really good discussion of the issues involved.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A function $f$ is increasing at $x$ if $f(t)\gt f(x)$ for every $t\gt x$ close enough to $x$ and $f(t)\lt f(x)$ for every $t\lt x$ close enough to $x$. More rigorously, one asks that there exists $\varepsilon\gt0$ such that, for every $(t,s)$ such that $x-\varepsilon\lt t\lt x\lt s\lt x+\varepsilon$, $f(t)\lt f(x)\lt f(s)$.

No notion of differentiability is needed. Consider for example the function $f$ defined by $f(t)=2t$ for every rational $t$ and $f(t)=t$ for every irrational $t$. Then $f$ is increasing at $x=0$ and only at $x=0$ while $f$ is nowhere differentiable.

Comment: Great. That definition makes sense. Do you know of any text book that uses this definition?

Comment: This definition, surely with @Douglas’s emendation, probably is the only one that makes sense, but I don’t believe I’ve ever seen it before. It prompts the immediate question of whether a function can be increasing at every point of an interval without being increasing *on* that interval.

Comment: Any textbook? I am afraid not. But the definition is natural to anybody studying the pathwise properties of random processes, most notably standard Brownian motion.

Comment: @Lubin (and others): See my 23 April 2006 AP-Calculus post [archived at Math Forum](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=4661014) for a reasonably complete discussion of these matters, as well as my 16 April 2010 AP-calculus post [also archived at Math Forum](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7041396).

Comment: I can think of at least one more definition that makes sense, namely that $f$ is increasing on every sufficiently small interval around $x$.  But as I haven't seen either definition in literature, I guess I'll defer to the one that makes sense in the Brownian motion context.

Comment: Example Textbook: Sohrab's Basic Real Analysis. It has following definition in Problem 3.6: A function $f\in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ is increasing at a point $x_0$ if there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $f(x)\leqslant f(x_0)\leqslant f(y)$ for all $x\in(x_0-\delta,x_0)$ and $y\in (x_0,x_0+\delta)$.

Comment: This definition is also given in Michael Spivak's *Calculus* (fourth edition) on page 217.

Comment: The Math Forum links I gave in a comment above no longer work, and their archive has been taken off the internet from what I understand. However, I think the 2006 post is what I've copied into this [16 May 2006 sci.math post archived by google](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/9kU61P-TLOs/m/H7bsXeNAHrkJ) (other posts in that thread may also be of interest). See also this [29 December 2008 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/OwjFRCdmCqQ/m/-kD760l0LN4J).

Comment: @Thomas: Landau, *Differential and Integral Calculus* (1934, 1950 translation), p. [88](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.141247/page/n89/mode/2up), Definition 27. // Similar: Hardy, *A Course of Pure Mathematics* (1967 10e), p. [178](https://books.google.com/books?id=3WAhAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA178), "Steadily increasing or decreasing functions"