# Example on Riemann integrability

Tags: real-analysis

I want an example of a measurable function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that

$(1)$ $f$ is strictly increasing almost every where,

$(2)$ Upper Riemann integral of $f$is $1$,

$(3)$ Lower Riemann integral of $f$ is $0$

$(4)$  $0<\int_{[0,1]}fdm <1  $ where $m$ is Lebesgue measure.  Can any one give Hints?

Comment: What do you mean by "$f$ is strictly increasing almost everywhere"?  Is that to say that there is a set $A\subset [0,1]$ of measure $1$ such that the restriction of $f$ to $A$ is an increasing function?

Comment: Omnomnomnom : "f" is strictly increasing almost every where means that the set of points where f is not strictly increasing has measure zero.

Comment: "$f$ is increasing at a point" is not a meaningful statement.  Or, if you mean something by it, you'll have to clarify what it is that you mean.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You could interpret "f is strictly increasing at $x$" as "There is an $\epsilon$ such that $\forall y \in (x-\epsilon,x) \,:\, f(y) < f(x)$ and $\forall y \in (x,x+\epsilon) \,:\, f(x) < f(y)$". Not sure how usefull that definition is, though.

Comment: @fgp for all I know, that could be what is really meant.  Importantly, that definition would preclude the existence of a counterexample.

Comment: @Math is there a context for this problem?  Is this how the problem is stated?  Again, your definition of "strictly increasing almost everywhere" matters, and the definition that you've given is meaningless.

Comment: Omnomnomnom:As to the concept of almost every where()a.e f" is strictly increasing almost every where means that the set of points where f is not  increasing has measure zero.

Comment: @Math what do you mean by $f$ is increasing at a point???

Comment: @Math: A function $f$ is increasing on a set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ if for any $x,y \in A$, we have $f(x) > f(y)$ whenever $x>y$.  We say that $f$ is increasing at a point $x$ if... ????

Comment: Note that if this is how the question was originally phrased, we're probably using the [wrong definition.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364576/can-a-function-be-increasing-at-a-point)

Answer (score 2):

Let $E \subset Q^c$ be a countable dense subset in $[0,1]$. Define

$f(x) : = \begin{cases}
      0 \mbox{ if } x \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]\\
      1 \mbox{ if } x \in E\\
      x \mbox{ otherwise }
      \end{cases}$

Answer (score 1):

An example of what I think you mean: define $A_1 = \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$, $A_2 = \{\sqrt{2}q:q \in \mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1]\}$, and $A_3 = [0,1]\setminus (A_1 \cup A_2)$.  Define
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & x \in A_1\\
1 & x \in A_2\\
x & x \in A_3
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: But upper Riemann sum is not 1.

Comment: Omnomnomnom :Thanks I think so but how can the upper Riemann integral be 1?

Comment: See answer below.

Comment: @Math see my latest edit.

Comment: @DiffeoR you still have to undelete your answer

Comment: I have undeleted it. Is it not visible ?

Comment: @DiffeoR never mind, it is visible.  I forgot to refresh.