# Is this function increasing at $x = 2$?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
3x^2+12x-1 & -1\leq x \leq 2 \\
37-x & 2\lt x \leq 3 \end{cases}$$

This function is obviously continous at $x=2$. Also, $f'(2)$ does not exist. Before $2$, the function is increasing, because $f'$ is positive. After $2$ it is decreasing.

The question asks if the function is increasing on $[-1,2]$. The function clearly is increasing on $[-1,2)$. But, at exactly $x=2$, how should I classify it? The left hand derivative is positive and the right hand derivative is negative.

The way I see it is that it should be increasing, because on approaching $2$ from the left, the function is increasing. Also, we are not allowed to go to the right of $2$. So it must be increasing. Am I right?

Edit:

To avoid confusion with [Can a function be increasing *at a point*?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364576/can-a-function-be-increasing-at-a-point?rq=1), let me clarify in that context. I don't wanna know if in general a function can be continuous at a point. I have a specific query about what happens when we restricted the period in which we are checking continuity.

Comment: Recall the definition of increasing; we say that $f$ is increasing on $(a,b)$ if $f(x)>f(y)$ whenever $x>y$ for $x,y\in (a,b)$...

Comment: Sorry, read that the wrong way round. Yes, it is increasing on $[-1,2]$. If you pick any two points $a<b$ in $[-1,2]$ you have $f(a)<f(b)$.

Comment: The title is "misleading" but nicely encapsulates your "point" of confusion.  Related to the earlier Question in that we define *increasing* functions on intervals (or at least on ordered domains), and then define increasing-at-a-point to mean increasing in a suitable neighborhood of the given point (locally).

Answer (score 1):

1. What is a function? A subset $f$ of $A\times B$ such that for each $a\in A$ there is exactly one $b\in B$ for which $(a, b)\in f.$ A function is  "its graph." The function $f$ in your first line ,and the function "$f$ restricted to the domain $[-1,2]$" are two different functions.
2. We can say that "a function $g$ is increasing at a point $p$" (when $p\in$ dom $(g)\;$) means that there exists $r>0$ such that (i) $y\in (p-r,p)\cap$ dom $(g)\implies g(y)\leq g(p),$ and (ii) $y\in (p,p+r)\cap$ dom $(g)\implies g(y)\geq g(p)$. Then we can say that $g$ is increasing iff $g $ is inceasing at each $p$ in its domain.